# Updates files on Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, heroku, paperclip

I have a text-file @ Amazon S3. This file needs to be appended with some text periodically. Is it possible to update the same file on Amazon-S3 or should it be a new file altogether? Am using Ruby on Rails & PaperClip.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to upload a new file.